# assign value in a list

Tags: python, list, limit

```
while True:
    p = []
    q = []
    H = []
    E = []
    for m in range(n):
        p = (i-d[m-2][1])/d[m-2][0]
        q.append(p)
    print q

    r = q[0]
    if r  < g[1][0]:
        r == g[1][0]
    elif r > g[1][1]:
        r == g[1][1]
    print r
```

For the problem of the coding above, I want to explain it in a simpler manner.

```
i = [3,5]

r = [5,6]

if i[0] < r[0]:
    i[0] == r[0]
    print i
```

However, i could not get `[5,5]` in this example, why? the output is still `[3,5]`

Comment: Always try the interpreter when stuck with these kinds of things. i[0] == r[0] will return `False`, which will make you realise that you've used the comparison operator instead of assigning any values. You want `=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following lines are comparisons rather than assignments:

```
    r == g[1][0]
    r == g[1][1]
    i[0] == r[0]
```

I suspect you meant to write

```
    r = g[1][0]
    r = g[1][1]
    i[0] = r[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
i[0] == r[0]
r == g[1][0]
r == g[1][1]
```

to (respectively)

```
i[0] = r[0]
r = g[1][0]
r = g[1][1]
```

`==` is a logical comparison (it tests whether the two values are equal and returns `False` or `True`). `=` is the assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
i[0] == r[0] --> i[0] = r[0]
r == g[1][0] --> r = g[1][0]
r == g[1][1] --> r = g[1][1]
```